# Build qt for raspberry pi3 arm64

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi3

I try to set up a cross compile build environment for raspberry-pi3 qt5.12 application. The target will run ubuntu 64bits (raspberry version) os and the host runs ubuntu 18.04 x86-64. I tried several tutorials found on the internet like this one :
https://medium.com/@amirmann/how-to-cross-compile-qt-for-raspberry-pi-3-on-linux-ubuntu-for-beginners-75acf2a078c

I try to set up this environment to put CI/CD for raspi application so I'd like to set it up without the raspberry physically connected to the host, only a mounted image if possible or a qemu process.

Whatever I try to do, the qt configuration failed with the following error :

```
$RPI_TOOLS/..../ld: cannot find crt1.o : No such file or directory
$RPI_TOOLS/..../ld: cannot find crti.o : No such file or directory
$RPI_TOOLS/..../ld: cannot find -lm
```

I tried to export a $LIBRARY_PATH environment variable with the path to those files but nothing changes.

Does anyone have already compiled qt 5.12 for raspberry pi3 64bits and can give me some clues/tutorials/help on how to do it ?

Thx guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my issues with the option -xplatform linux-aarch64-gnu-arm when starting qt configure script. Before this I chroot into the raspi-rootfs with qemu-static and install the dependencies with apt.